# if $P(x_{0})=0$, but $\lim_{ x \to x_{0} }(x-x_{0})\left( \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \right) = \text{finite}$, then function is analytic at $x=x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm currently learning about Differential Equations and the textbook I'm using (by DiPrima) says the following:

> For polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ that has no common factors, if $P(x_{0})=0$, but $\lim_{ x \to x_{0} }(x-x_{0})\left( \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \right) = \text{finite}$, then $(x-x_{0})\left( \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \right)$ is analytic at $x=x_{0}$

I'm confused how $f(x)=\frac{(x-x_{0}) Q(x)}{P(x)}$ could be analytic if $f(x)$ is not even defined at $x =x_0$. I know if the limit is finite then the $(x-x_{0})$ should cancel out as $Q(x)$ and $P(x)$ are just polynomials, so do we just define $f(x_{0})$ by including the point in this removable continuity?

**Also, if $Q(x)$ and $P(x)$ are instead analytic functions is $x=x_{0}$ a removable discontinuity as well?(This is only part left to be answered)**

P.S. Although it is not required to answer this question, if it is possible can you also include some hints on why this function is analytic?

Comment: "...do we just define $f(x_0)$ by including the point in this removable continuity?" This is exactly what we do. It can be tedious to write out the piecewise expression for a function with many removable discontinuities, so these values are usually not declared explicitly.

Comment: Write $P(x)=(x-x_0)^k\widetilde{P}(x)$, where $\widetilde{P}(x)$ is a polynomial such that $\widetilde{P}(x_0)\neq 0$. Note that $Q$ and have no common factor (by assumption) and hence $Q(x_0)\neq 0$ (otherwise $(x-x_0)$ would be a common factor). Thus, we get $$(x-x_0)\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{Q(x)}{(x-x_0)^{k-1}\widetilde{P}(x)}.$$ As $Q(x_0)\neq 0$ and $\widetilde{P}(x_0)\neq 0$ we get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}(x-x_0)\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{1}{(x-x_0)^{k-1}} \frac{Q(x_0)}{\widetilde{P}(x_0)}.$$ This is only finite if $k=1$. [Cont.]

Comment: [Cont] If $k=1$, we get for $x\neq x_0$ $$(x-x_0)\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{Q(x)}{\widetilde{P}(x)}.$$ We use the RHS as our function and get rid of our removable singularity. As it is a quotient of polynomials and the denominator does not vanish for $x=x_0$, we get that our function is analytic at $x=x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Now I understand why it is analytic when $P(x) \text{and} Q(x)$ are polynomials. What about the second part though? Does function has a removable discontinuity when we assume $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are instead analytic functions?

Comment: @LutzLehmann You are clearly correct. I was just a bit in a hurry and did not want to post an incomplete answer, which is why it became two comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first consider the case when $P,Q$ are polynomials. If $P(x_0)=0$, then $(x-x_0)$ is a factor of $P(x)$ and we write

$$ P(x) = (x-x_0)^k \widetilde{P}(x) $$

where $k$ is a positive integer and $\widetilde{P}(x)$ is a polynomial such that $\widetilde{P}(x_0)\neq 0$. Hence, we get

$$ (x-x_0)\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} = \frac{Q(x)}{(x-x_0)^{k-1} \widetilde{P}(x)}. $$

As $Q(x_0)\neq 0$ and $\widetilde{P}(x_0)\neq 0$, we get

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}  (x-x_0)\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{Q(x)}{(x-x_0)^{k-1} \widetilde{P}(x)}
= \frac{Q(x_0)}{\widetilde{P}(x_0)} \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{1}{(x-x_0)^{k-1}}.$$

Requiring that the limit above remains finite is equivalent to $k=1$. In this case, we have for $x\neq x_0$

$$ (x-x_0)\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} = \frac{Q(x)}{ \widetilde{P}(x)}. $$

As $Q(x), \widetilde{P}(x)$ are polynomials not vanishing at $x=x_0$ we get that the RHS is analytic at $x=x_0$ and we can use the RHS as a definition for the extension of the LHS for $x=x_0$. In different words, $(x-x_0)Q(x)/P(x)$ has a removable singularity at $x=x_0$.

In the case when $Q,P$ are general analytic functions, the same result remains true. However, it is a bit more difficult to prove and goes by the name Riemann extension theorem.